# questions for my 13 year old's STEM class. (Users of Potassium)

Tags: safety, metal

Would you please answer the following questions for my 13 year old girl's STEM class?

1. Do you have a story about a time something went wrong using Potassium?
2. What are some of the precautions you take when using Potassium?
3. What are some thing Potassium is used for?
4. Is there a suitable substitute?

Answer (score 2):

Most common use would be making potassium alkoxides by reaction with alcohols.

Have also seen it used as a drying agent for preparing ultra-dry THF. This leaves potentially hazardous residues for the person who has to clean the still. Seen more than one fire because of potassium residues at the bottom of the flask.

There are certainly other drying agents for preparing dry solvents. But if your chemistry requires a potassium compound and not sodium or lithium then that's what you have to do.

It is usually supplies as chunks stored under liq. Paraffin. Handling it under hexanes with appropriate gloves, goggles etc is safe enough. I hope I don't have to tell you to keep it away from water.